# Icons within initWithStyleDeafult on app

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to set an icon up in the place of this little black square.  I could even make it a single letter of text.  The trick is, I want to do it based on an attribute of the cell.

So my question is two fold.  How do I change that box, and how can I do an if, elseif, else for the three categories the attributes are in?

Let me know what code you'd like to see, and I'll edit here.

Thanks for any help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbM3e.png

****************Edit**********************

I've got the syntax for the icons

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Urgent.png"];
```

Now my question is how do I declare and utilize one of the attributes of the cell/item for my if statement?

Here's my code for the elements in my store

```
 if (self.changeList.count>0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < self.changeList.count; i++) {
             NSDictionary *coItem = self.changeList[i];

             [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]
              addItemWithApproverEid:coItem[@"approverEid"]
              assignmentGroup:coItem[@"assignmentGroup"]
              changeOrder:coItem[@"changeOrder"]
              subcategory:coItem[@"subCategory"]
              title:coItem[@"title"]


              ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the image in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, so you have access to all of the data for that cell, just use that data to determine what image you want to show.

Set your default image, then override based on your logic.

Comment: I think I've found my issue.  Whomever coded the API messed up.  I'll check tomorrow and edit.